# How to display legend in bottom right corner instead of top right?

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

Normally the legend appears in the top-right corner when using the command

```
legend('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')
```

But that blocks my curves.

How to place it in the bottom-right corner instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's simple:

```
legend('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'Location','SouthEast');
```

How then does it distinguish between labels and arguments? It doesn't. So if you say

```
legend('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'Location');
```

it will throw an error. So, if "Location" is one of your labels, use

```
legend({'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'Location'});
```

Comment: `'NorthWest'` for top left corner and `'SouthWest'` for bottom left corner, as can be imagined.

Comment: Also, note that the legend can be dragged with the mouse for finer position adjustment

Comment: Props for handling the case that some weirdo has a series called `Location`. You are a true programmer!

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev, Can  you help me when I used>      plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0],p4[0],p5[0]), ('Promoters', 'Detractors', 'aa','bb','cc')) Then how to pass location in parameters.